# How should I Install Android OS in my Samsung Android Mobile?

Tags: installation

I have a lot trouble with Android mobile using.Main problem it is very slow and again and again frieze and do not have good throughput.
So I figure out a lot of solution and also apply and none of the work which some time relief and after again same condition.So finally I conclud to chenge OS which help full so provide link here [Which Android mobile](http://tech.firstpost.com/product/mobile-phones/grand-quattro-gt-i8552-specification-320912.html) please check OS version and comtiblity and give me advice which OS will be fit in this android and How to install.
I read a lot about it. I found [XDA](http://www.xda-developers.com/) but can not find the way to install.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/grand-quattro) and reading their stickied posts and just read... a lot, there is still some active developing on this legacy device so your questions will likely get answered within a few days of posting.

Samsungs are generally flashed with new ROMs in the same way, use ODIN to flash TWRP, backup the existing ROM with TWRP, flash new ROM and Gapps with TWRP. Since some of these steps are device specific, best to ask in the forums for your specific device as to the best current methods and versions of software.

Unless you can ask a more specific question, the scope of this general question is beyond a simple answer.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to flash a brand new firmware on the phone. I found two versions for your phone with different plateform - One on Qualcomm MSM (MSM8625Q Snapdragon 200) and the other on MTK (MT6572). Since you've provide no clear description, I'll post two solutions as well.

1. For MSM plateform, you'll need Odin (Heindall if your computer runs Mac OS) to flash your phone: Go [here](http://firmwarefile.com/samsung-gt-i8552) and download the firmware and follow the instructions on how to flash.
2. For MTK platefore (also cloned phone), you'll need a flasher called SP Flashtool and a flashable ROM. Look [here](http://www.needrom.com/download/gt-i8552-mt6572/).

[Update]:

3. For custom ROM (to upgrade to a hi version of Android OS, e.g. Android 5.0, go [here](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-update-a-Samsung-Galaxy-Grand-Quattro-GT-I8552-to-Android-5-0) and follow instructions carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47252/discussion-between-jsroyal-and-esqmo).

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to change the OS 
If you are using a Samsung phone in recent years 
Then it is most likely running android 
You could root it but i will NOT recommend it as it will lead to unforeseen circumstances.
To solve your problem you could try deleting some files and Apps that you do not use.

Comment: He means to flash the phone. Not changing from Android to whatsoever